# Show Window on largest screen using Adobe AIR

Tags: javascript, air

I'm building an Adobe AIR application in HTML/JavaScript that will use two windows, once of which will be display on the largest screen available (if available).

The code is as follows:

```
function showProjector(){

    if(air.Screen.screens.length > 1) {

        if(htmlLoader) {

            // Projector is already shown

        } else {

            // Create a new window that will become the projector screen
            var options = new air.NativeWindowInitOptions(); 
            options.systemChrome = air.NativeWindowSystemChrome.NONE; 
            options.transparent = true;
            options.type= air.NativeWindowType.LIGHTWEIGHT;

            var htmlLoader = air.HTMLLoader.createRootWindow(false, options, false);  
            htmlLoader.window.nativeWindow.visible = true;

            // Add content to new window
            htmlLoader.load(new air.URLRequest('Projector.html'));

            // Make the window appear on the biggest screen
            htmlLoader.bounds = air.Screen.screens[1];

            // Make it full screen
            htmlLoader.stage.displayState = runtime.flash.display.StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;

        }

    } else {

        // Show error that you need a projector screen
        alert('You need a projector screen');
    }       
}
```

I've handled the parts checking if more than one screen is available and if the projector is already being displayed. But need to find out which is the biggest screen and make sure that the current window DOES not move to it, and the new `htmlLoader` one DOES move it to.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding the largest screen:

```
var largestScreen = null;
for( var index = 0; index < Air.Screen.screens.length; ++index) {
    var currentScreen = Air.Screen.screens[index];
    if( largestScreen == null ){
        largestScreen = currentScreen;  
    }
    else{
        //Defining largest screen as biggest total area.
        var currentArea = currentScreen.bounds.width * currentScreen.bounds.height;
        var largestArea = largestScreen.bounds.width * largestScreen.bounds.height;
        if(currentArea > largestArea) {
            largestScreen = currentScreen;
        }
    }
}
```

Setting the projector window to the largest screen needs to happen on creation

```
var htmlLoader = air.HTMLLoader.createRootWindow(false, options, false, largestScreen.bounds);
```

See reference:

- [flash.display.NativeWindow](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/reference/html/flash/display/NativeWindowInitOptions.html)
- [flash.html.HTMLLoader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/reference/html/flash/html/HTMLLoader.html#location)
- [flash.display.Screen](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/reference/html/flash/display/Screen.html)

Comment: Is that JavaScript or ActionScript? I know in AIR you can use both at the same time inside script tags... but wondered if I could do it using just JavaScript? Thanks.

Comment: There's very little difference between them. The only thing that shouldve been a problem for JS would be the first line. See edit.

Comment: How do I then make the projector screen show on the largest screen? as when I do this: `htmlLoader.bounds = largestScreen;` it complains that it can't set the property bounds. Thanks.

Comment: Cool that works :) Marked as answered and bounty awarded. Thanks. Fancy having a look at this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24240491/communicate-between-two-adobe-air-windows