# Communicate between two Adobe AIR windows

Tags: javascript, air

I am building an Adobe AIR (HTML/JavaScript) app for a client who wants to display a game interface on two screens. One screen is where the user will interact with the game itself, the other screen (shown on a projector) will show the game to an audience. **The contents of screen 2 is NOT the same as screen 1, so it's NOT a case of mirroring.**

An example of this, is a bingo game where the user will click buttons on screen 1 to pull out numbers, etc. And screen 2 will just show the number grid and next number pulled out to the audience who are playing the game. So you can imagine this in a hall of people, with screen 1 being displayed to the guy on stage, and screen 2 being projected to everyone else in the hall. So screen 2 has no interaction and ONLY displays data.

How would I handle this? As I need to be able to send commands to the other window to make it show numbers, update the number grid, etc.

I've looked at doing something like:

```
projectorWindow.setWindowReference(air.NativeApplication.nativeApplication.openedWindows[1].stage.getChildAt(0).window);

projectorWindow.sendNumber( 88 );
```

But does anyone have a better idea? Existing examples of doing this?

---

**Second question:**

Also in order to make the windows know what each is talking about, I presume I will have to load the EXACT same code into each one so basically load a HTML file like: `Bingo.html` and then pass a query string to tell it what mode to run in... e.g. `Bingo.html?mode=user` and `Bingo.html?mode=audience` does that sound right? Or would there be a better way to do this?

So for example:

```
function loadGame(game) {

    mainWindow.load(new air.URLRequest(game + '.html?mode=user'));

    projectorWindow.load(new air.URLRequest(game + '.html?mode=audience'));         
}
```

Not quite sure how I'll trigger the different UI elements based on the query string yet... but is this the best way to build a split screen game using AIR? Or could I do it better?

Comment: are these two air apps gonna be running on the same machine? couldnt you use localconnection for that? (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/LocalConnection.html).

Comment: But they're not two apps. It's the same app with two windows.

Comment: i dont know if there is a way to communicate between air and its embedded html but wont it be easier if your air app load a single html (parent html), and the parent html will spawn two windows, userWindow and audienceWindow. I havent tried spawning a new html window from air app myself but in theory, it should be easier for your two window to communicate, and parent window being the mediator. you can also explore the more modern approach: https://github.com/diy/intercom.js/. will there be code logic on the air app or does it only serve as a loader/shell to the html apps?

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean by having a single html that spawns two windows as I'm sure that's what I already have. Could you perhaps show a code example for this? Thanks.